# React - renderSubtreeIntoContainer: Use case example

Tags: reactjs

I've recently started using react and so far I'm enjoying it a lot.

However I'm struggling with the documentation.

I've seen some mentions of `unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer` / `renderSubtreeIntoContainer` mentioned here ([github](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4301)).

In which context would I use this? How would I use it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One of the use cases is "portals" - when you need to render a component outside the react app, but still control it as usual.
For example - https://github.com/tajo/react-portal/blob/master/lib/portal.js#L135